# Node.js Memory Leaks

Tags: memory, node.js, buffer

My program is a CLI network client (my first networking project) and so far I have been able to solve all the problems I have had. It decodes and writes 100% of the data correctly.

However, after running for an hour or two (it has varied), it crashes because Node is out of memory. I suspect that the use of node Buffers is the source of the leak, because they are allocated outside of V8's heap, but to my knowledge there is no way to control their GC. I use Buffers pretty heavily in my parsing code, and that is what the Node Socket 'data' event gives out.

Right now, nothing else is really going on that could be causing the leak. Also, it seems like the memory usage stays ~10M for the first half hour or so, then it starts rapidly rising.

My questions are, are there any ways to solve leaks that involve Buffers? Are there any quirks with Buffers that I should know about? Are there any obvious courses of action?

Comment: What version of node are you using, if it's not 0.6.11 then upgrade

Comment: so you haven't really profiled the memory leaks? you're only guessing? use node-inspector for searching the real memory leak!

Answer (score -1):

You can try unit test your code using [Mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) and when memory leaks is detected, the test will fail.

Comment: I do not believe this is true. I do not believe Mocha detects memory leaks!

Comment: Unit testing is not for memory leaks! You test a minimal function unit.